# List of extensions registered with an application

Tags: windows, file, file-type, file-association, win32-process

For an application (for ex: excel.exe), I would like to know what all extensions (for ex: .xlt, .xlsx etc) are registered with application (excel.exe). How to achieve it?

Platform: Windows

Languages: C/C++/C#

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, file extension registrations can be a bit complex to work with.  There is no definitive API to extract the kind of information you are looking for.  There is the [`IQueryAssociations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761400.aspx.) interface, but it doesn't give you a whole lot of flexibility in how it queries.  It is more of a 1-to-1 query, but you are looking for a Many-to-1 query instead.  So you will have to dig in the Registry directly for that information.

Use `RegOpenKeyEx()` to open the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` hive and enumerate all of its immediate subkeys with `RegEnumKeyEx()`, looking for key names that start with a period. That will give you the list of known file extensions.

For each `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\<ext>` key, check for:

1. a `(Default)` value that contains a non-blank string.  If present, that is the file extension's ProgID. You can open the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\<ProgID>` key and see if it has any `shell\<verb>\command` subkeys that contain the application path (there may be multiple `<verb>` values present, so you will have to enumerate them).  If none, check if the ProgID key has a `CLSID` subkey.  If present, its `(Default)` value will be the `CLSID` of a COM object that handles everything associated with that ProgID.  You can open the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\<CLSID>` key and check if it has an `InprocHandler`, `InprocHandler32`, `InprocServer` or `InprocServer32` subkey containing the full path to an EXE or DLL file that owns that COM object.
2. a `PersistentHandler` subkey.  If present, its `(Default)` value will be the `CLSID` of a COM object that handles that file extension.  You can check the CLSID as needed.
3. an `OpenWithProgIds` subkey. If present, then it will contain a list of ProgIDs that you can check as needed.
4. an `OpenWithList` subkey.  If present, it will contain a list of registered app names. You can open the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\<AppName>` key to get the full path to each app.

There are a few other possibilities (ShellEx keys, DDE keys, other Shell-related COM object keys, etc), but I think you see the point.  There is potentially a LOT of digging to figure out which app handles a given file extension.